# HTTPS and error code 503

Tags: tls, error-handling

I tried to visit a HTTPS page and server responded with 503 response - currently unavailable. In address bar, there was an address of that Facebook page, but it was not HTTPS but HTTP, probably because of server overload. I know that it is very unusual, but it happened. I want to know if my visit to that page is recorded by ISP or not. I'm also using Google open DNS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your ISP has records of your attempt to visit the original page.  That request left your browser, went through the ISP and to Facebook, which sent back a response of a 503 error, which your ISP also has records of.

Comment: Not true for https, Url is encrypted and provider can only see domain name, not the page you visited...

Comment: Request left my browser but NOT to my ISP DNS server, I use Google Open DNS...Not true for HTTPS, Url is encrypted and provider can only see domain name, not the page you visited... My question is more about DNS provider... Because I use Google DNs....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499591/are-https-urls-encrypted

Comment: I hope you understand me now... What if you used third party DNS provider as Google Open DNS?

Comment: I understand.  The DNS traffic had to be carried to the google DNS by your ISP, right?  But, that DNS request would only contain the domain, not the full URL.  I understand you care about the full URL being exposed, not the facebook.com domain.

Comment: Yes that is true.I only care if full address is recorded and exposed in this specific case.But I don't understand the answer. Request was sent using https from search engine and http page with error code 503 opened. So I only care if isp recorded the http adress because the server was down...

Comment: I'm searching for answers about this specific case for days... Please help it is very important to me!